# Can you insert with a mix of of subquery and values?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have a procedure that is receiving some values from our application, I need to insert these static values and the results of a subquery to one of our tables.  Is this possible with one insert statement?  So it would look like this

```
Insert into table
values 
(value1, value2, value3, (select testdata from dual));

The resulting table would look like:
value1 | value2 | value 3 | ROW 1 FROM SUBQUERY
value1 | value2 | value 3 | ROW 2 FROM SUBQUERY
```

I know that if I was only using a subquery I would omit the values command and vice versa with actual values.  Does anyone have experience with this one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but you do it only with a `select`:

```
Insert into table
    select value1, value2, value3, testdata
    from dual;
```

That is, you add the values as constants on the `select` line.

Comment: Would this work if my values (value1, value2, value3) are IN variables and my testdata is a multi-row and multi-column subquery?

Comment: @user2600900 . . . Yes and yes.

Answer (score 0):

Use INSERT INTO tablename SELECT xxx FROM command.

```
INSERT INTO tablename ( col1, col2, ... colN)
-- select rows from first subquery
SELECT x1, x2, ... xN FROM ......
UNION ALL
-- select rows from second subquery
SELECT y1, y2, ... yN FROM ......
```